# Unable to pass a text to another forms listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I am trying to pass a value from textbox1 of my form3 to the `ListBox` of my `form1`.

Here is the code for `form3` :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 f1 = new Form1(textBox1.Text);
    f1.Show();
}
```

And here it is what is wrote in form1 :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1(string something)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBox1.Items.Add(something);       

    }
```

The error is:

> Form1' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: You'd better add your code and error as text - this way it can't be put into search and/or properly read when question displayed.. Did you try to add one parameterless constructor anyway?

Comment: it started to work, but i got an another error message. I want to fill up a listbox on a form with items from another form. pls help.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. You can use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42907113/edit) button below your post to add information to it.

Comment: what exactly is now the problem? you need to post more code if you want help. Please don't post screenshots of code.

Comment: i will try this. i am new here, how can i add code lines in this comment box? thak you for the quick help

Comment: don't add code in the comment box. Please add the code into your post. As I already wrote: There is an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42907113/edit) button right below the tags of your post. click it or click the word in my comment (I linked it to the function) and add the relevant code

Comment: thank u, i edited the post. I am really under time pressure, i am not in good shape at the moment....

Comment: you have data in form3 and now you want this data in form1, so far I got you. Now in which order to you open your forms? 1-> 2-> 3 ? or do you start with 3?

Comment: form1 is a welcome screen of a game, there is the listbox for the highscores. form2 is the game itself. form3 is the game over window, where you have to enter your name. I would like to pass this value into the listbox of form 1. thx .

Comment: i edited my post, hope it is easier to understand.

Comment: If any answer was helpful to solve your problem, it would be kind if you can mark it as accepted. These 2 articles: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) can help.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the line where this error comes from (). I would wildly guess that there is a line in your code that uses a parameterless constructor like :

```
Form1 foo = new Form1();
```

or even if it is the starting form:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

You should overload the constructor and not simply change it, since it is auto-generated it might highly probably be that it is already used in this form somewhere. Just add a second constructor:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form(string something)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBox.Items.Add(something);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

> trying to pass a value from textbox1 of my form3 to the listbox of my form1

This is a slightly different problem then your error suggested in the first place. A different approach would be advisable. The constructor is useless, because it will create a different instance/object which is not the same that you see on the screen! In other words, all Elements will loose their values!

One of many solutions can be to create a method which would add items to the `ListBox` in the class `Form1`:

```
public void AddItemToListBox(string s)
{
    listBox.Items.Add(something);
}
```

and pass the instance of the current window `Form1` via `Form2` to `Form3`. 
Have a variable in each class(`Form2` and `Form3`) of type `Form1`

```
public Form1 temp_form1;
```

and pass the instance of the starting window `Form1` to the variable `temp_form1` when you call `Form2` in the class **Form1**:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.temp_form1 = this; // "this" stands for the instance of the current object
```

and the same hold for `Form3` when you call it in the class **Form2**:

```
Form3 form3 = new Form3();
form3.temp_form1 = this.temp_form1;
```

At the end just call the method to update the listbox in the class **Form3**:

```
temp_form1.AddItemToListBox("yourstring");
```

Comment: exactly i have this line:  Form1 foo = new Form1();  but how to call the form in the another form without this?

Comment: @RobertRimai I tried to make my post a little clearer. How is it going? managed to get your data to the starting window?

Comment: thank you in advance, i will check it soon, but now i am extremely tired.

Comment: I had to drop the multiple form function. I will widen my knowledge, and come back soon. It made me very happy, that you people specially Mong Zhu helped me within a second with my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Do not delete the default constructor of your form, leave it there and add another one with your custom parameters under it instead.

```
public Form1()
{
    //Default constructor
    InitializeComponent();     
}

public Form1(string something)
{
    //Your custom constructor
    InitializeComponent();
    listBox1.Items.Add(something);       
}
```

Comment: But i have a problem again. When starting a new game, it overwrites the content of the listbox, not adds the another name. I want to contain the listbox the highscores, sorted. thx in advance!

Comment: Sorry, i want to thank you too. I am really exhausted, and under time pressure. I am totally happy to have people  like u on earth. But why it does not add the item to the listbox, it overwrites always the first line. I need the listbox to show the highscores and names and sorted. pls help.

Comment: @RobertRimai when you start a new game, how exactly do you do that`?

Comment: After entering the player name in form3, it passes the name to the form1 listbox. Hides form3, and shows up form1 again. From form1 i began a new game, which is displayed by form2. ty.

Comment: are you sure that you don't create a new `Form1` each time? Have you read the second part of my answer?

Comment: I mistyped something i guess. The constructor work fine, only the listbox is always filled up in line1 with the new name....

Comment: No i amm not sure. Probably u are right. It creates a new form1 each time. How to aviod this?

Comment: Yes, but to be honest i do not get it. I am a very beginner.

Comment: @RobertRimai then my friend you need to do a little more basic research. The idea is that you have one instance inside the other to be able to pass data around. But is has to be the one of the original window!

Comment: Where to put this method that fills up the listbox? And where to put the temp_form1?

Comment: "Where to put this method that fills up the listbox? " it is written in my answer: "create a method which would add items to the ListBox in Form1". The method has to be in `Form1` because the `ListBox` is not public and cannot be accessed from any other class! :)

Comment: "And where to put the temp_form1" in `Form2` and `Form3`

Comment: The only thing i need to finish this game is to know ho to get back to my form1 without creating a new form1, so the content of the listbox does not disappear. Should is throw away the new constructor?

Comment: "Should is throw away the new constructor? " yes, if as you say you hide form1 and at each game make a new window, then after 30 games you will have 30 hidden windows flooding your RAM, you don't really want this

Comment: I am done for today, i want to thank all of you. I will widen my knowledge in the near futue, but now i have to finish this task until wednesday.